# Changing the store of treepanel after an event

Tags: extjs, treeview

Im quite stuck on changing the store of Extjs TreePanel, after some specific event I retrieved those values from the server :

```
  "{"listType":false,"text":"root","children":[{"listType":false,"text":"Window","children":[{"listType":false,"text":"Window","children":[{"listType":false,"text":"height","children":[],"leaf":true},{"listType":false,"text":"items","children":[{"listType":false,"text":"border","children":[],"leaf":true},{"listType":false,"text":"store","children":[],"leaf":true},{"listType":true,"text":"columns","children":[],"leaf":false},{"listType":false,"text":"xtype","children":[],"leaf":true}],"leaf":false},{"listType":false,"text":"layout","children":[],"leaf":true},{"listType":false,"text":"title","children":[],"leaf":true},{"listType":false,"text":"width","children":[],"leaf":true}],"leaf":false}],"leaf":false}],"leaf":false}"
```

And I want to update the Treepanel 's store from that, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to change the store, you just need new data. Something of this sort:

```
var root = treePanel.getRootNode();
root.removeAll();
root.appendChild(objectOrArrayWithChildren);
```